# External HDD start working in USB2 mode on Macbook pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, external-disk, hdd

I have an external Toshiba HDD which lights blue light when it is connected to my MacBook.

After last MacOS update I noticed that it light white (in each of 4 ports), which means that it works in USB2 mode.

First I thought it is a cable issue, but with other cable it still lights white.
I tried to connect it to my iPad and there it flashes blue.

Is it a software or hardware issue?

External HDD works fine but I suspect some physical issues with my MacBook.

Comment: What speed does the Mac show for the connection? The System Information application should be able to display the connection speed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, it says Up to 480 Mb/s (System Report -> Hardware -> USB)